# Are Projections $p$ and $q$ in a C$^{*}$-algebra $A$ equal if $p\leq q\leq tp$ for some $t\in[0,\infty)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, spectral-theory, c-star-algebras

I am working on Exercise 3.11 (ii) in Rordam's book. This is where the motivation for my question (which is in the title) comes from. It is the last step I need to finish off the problem. If it is false in general, is there some condition on $t$ or on the projections $p$ and $q$ that make the result true?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if $t\in[0,1)$ then $p=0$ (since $p\leq tp$), so $0\leq q\leq 0$ and thus $q=0$.  Now if $t\in [1,\infty)$, then by taking successive roots we have 
$$p\leq q\leq t^\frac{1}{2^n}p$$ 
for all $n\in \mathbb N$.  Hence $p\leq q \leq p$, and thus $p=q$.

Comment: Thank you very much. Just to confirm, I guess you mean $p\leq q\leq t^{\frac{1}{2^{n}}}p$ in the display formula, right?

Comment: Oh yes, thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 2):

If $t=0$, $p=0=q$.

If $t\ne0$, from $q\leq tp$ we have 
$$
(1-p)q(1-p)\leq t(1-p)p(1-p)=0. 
$$
So 
$$
0=(1-p)q(1-p)=[q(1-p)]^*(1-p)q,
$$
implying that $(1-p)q=0$. That is $q=pq$, from there $q\leq p$.

Comment: My pleasure. These are very basic manipulations with projections that, in my opinion, are not emphasized enough.